# Problems With External Display Through VGA Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, vga

When I connect my laptop to my TV with a VGA problem, the TV says no signal and the screen is not detected by Ubuntu. When I run `xrandar` I get the following:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   1366x768      60.07*+  40.04  
   1280x720      59.97  
   1152x768      59.95  
   1024x768      59.95  
   800x600       59.96  
   848x480       59.94  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94  
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DisplayPort-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axi y axis)
```

My TV Is a TV that is Made Locally In my Country It's Model is
Grouhy 32 inch FULL HD led tv EH-10000

Comment: Please advise the make and model of the TV, for it may not be compatible with your video display adapter. Once you have that information, please click [edit] and add it into your question.